# NLB Multiple HTTPS sites - How Many IP Address Do I Need

Tags: ssl, https, nlb

I have been asked to setup NLB unicast for SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 WFE and 2 Web Applications using SSL/HTTPS.

I know with Unicast, you need two NIC, one for management and one for the cluster node.

I know at an IIS level I will need a unique IP address for each Web Application.

How many Cluster IP (VIP) will I need for the two Web Applications?

Do I need a unique IP for the Cluster IP each FQDN of the web app or can I one Cluster IP and map it to several FQDN (Web App URL)?

2 IP - Management
4 IP - IIS Binding (1 ip * 2 (web app https) * 2 (number of WFE servers))
? IP - Cluster IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One. The one VIP goes to the two NIC card IP addresses that you set up in NLB as each node.

- Cluster VIP goes to the FQDN address (http://sharepoint.domain.com)

The NLB nodes are those IP Addresses that are members of the cluster
- Web Front End 1
- Web Front End 2

Use Multicast. You should be able to use the cluster IP for all FQDNs, just point the DNS for each to the cluster VIP.

- sharepoint.domain.com -> Cluster VIP (10.0.0.1)
- projects.domain.com -> Cluster VIP (10.0.0.1)
- etc.etc.

Here is a good article about it: http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/05/29/prepare-sharepoint-farm-part-3-prepare-nlb-for-sharepoint-web-front-end-wfe-servers.aspx